# rolling 3-month average on past financials

Tags: sql, sql-server, rolling-average

Use the data warehouse that is part of the "AdventureWorks 2016 and Scripts for SQL Server 2016 CTP3" you previously installed from the Course and Topic Materials to complete the assignment.

The finance department wants to be able to project future financing details. The department manager has sent you a request for a rolling 3-month average on past financials.

Please note that when SQL queries are run, results are generated in the form of data. This data should be exported and saved to an Excel file for a visual check of accuracy.

Create a Word document that includes the SQL query code used to explore the database tables and write a query that retrieves finance amounts from "FactFinance" in the "AdventureWorksDW2016CTP3" database and returns those amounts, organized by month, and showing a 3-month rolling average.

Comment: What have you tried? What roadblocks have you faced trying to solve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly an assignment that they want the answer for without trying

Comment: SO is here to help you with problems you are facing, not to provide an exam/coursework writing service.  If you try to solve this youself and get stuck, you will find people here willing to help with that particular issue, but I for one am not going to give you a free pass on your assessments.

Comment: I will revise the question. Im apologies